# How do add CodeIgniter code to new PHP project in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, codeigniter

I am new to eclipse and CodeIgniter. The setup I am attempting to create is described here:
[Eclipse/CI Setup](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/69098/)
 I want to setup two PHP projects in Eclipse:

1) CI_CORE - I want to put the CI 'system' source in this project.
2) myApplication - This will be the contents of the 'application' director.

Its seems that when one creates a new project in Eclipse it creates a folder in the workspace. But I cannot figure out how to import preexisting source into this folder.

The other option that appears is, "Create project from existing source". I cannot use this choice as it tells me that I "cannot create a project in workspace".

So how can I include my CI source into a new Eclipse project? I would like to make use of autocomplete which is why I was trying the suggestion in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the workspace cannot be the same as where your project is going to be created. I don't understand why not but that was how I worked around this.

I simply changed the workspace to another location and then created a project and pointed this project to where my source lives. All is well.